# Class not found exception when executing JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using an external, third-party .JSON jar file for my MapReduce code but when I run the project on my EC2 instance, I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
```

on the console in my EC2 instance. Why is this the case?

I have the third-party library added to my External Libraries through the Configured Build Path so I do not get any errors locally. However, when I export the project as a JAR (with Hadoop, MapReduce, and this JSON jar file) and run it on my EC2 instance, I am getting the exception mentioned.

It is worth noting - this EC2 instance has Hadoop installed and is able to run MapReduce jobs. I am just wondering how I can get the JSON far file to be read by the EC2 instance and why it wasn't able to be processed if I configured my Build Path to do so.

This is the JSON Jar: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Comment: Have you built fat-jar from your project? Or is it a simple JAR without dependencies ?

Comment: I edited my question to reference the JAR I am trying to add.

Comment: Okay, but how do You exactly build a JAR ?

Comment: I have a project with three JAR files, the Hadoop, MapReduce, and this JSON. I export the project into one JAR file and try to run it on the instance. The instance can't identify the JSON jar.

Comment: Okay, but what method are You using for creating the JAR exactly. I'm asking because it seems that You are creating the standard jar that does not have the JSON library included, have You verified that it is indeed included in the JAR ?

Comment: I fiugured it out - I needed to add the JSON jar to Hadoop's classpath within the instance.